# Checking if user has unsaved data in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exit, prompt

I have the following code...

```
    var leave_page_confirm=false;

    if ($(':input.common_class').val().length !== 0) {

        var leave_page_confirm=true;

    }

    window.onbeforeunload = save_data_check;

      function save_data_check()
      {

        if (leave_page_confirm) {
          return "You have unsaved information on the page.";

        }

      }
```

I'm trying to see if any inputs on the page have value. If they don't then you can leave the page without a message. If they do, then there is a message you asking if you would like to leave the page. All of the inputs on my page have a common class.

Comment: `$(':input.common_class').val()` is incorrect. It must be `$('input.common_class').val()`. Also, do not use `var` the second time.

Comment: Made the edits. Still no cigar.

Comment: Well, pls also edit your question, which leaves no confusion for the ones that post answers! And also, what kind of inputs are we talking about? text, radio, checkbox? Post your HTML too.

Comment: All types of imputs. They a share that same common class though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information about the logic I have followed:
This code doesn't save anything, if you need to store some information just with JS, so on the client computer and this will depend on the cache, you can use the cookie(the information are temporary since rely on cookies that can be deleted, so maybe you can store the unsaved values to wait the user to submit them).
The first snippet is based on the idea that the inputs will not be cleared once you save the information(they will keep the information), this means that js checks if the user makes any change to them (can be smarter, maybe check if the value is really different from the beginning one) and set  var to `true/false`, once the user leaves the page then var is checked.

The second script is based on the idea that the inputs are part of a form or something like this, so once it get submitted the inputs will be cleared.
if the user leaves the page the code check if the are any non-empty (saved or not) value.

To sum up:

- the first checks **if any change has been made** to the input
- the second one check **if the input contains** a value

I don't understand the unsaved data: unsaved data or empty values? I mean if a user save a non empty value and then clean the input?
This is what I thought: basically every time the input change it sets the `saved` var to `false` and once you hit the button save (or every other logic) it sets the value to `true`, otherwise once you unload the page the script check the var to see if it is `true` or `false`
HTML:

```
<input type='input' class='test' />
<input type='input' class='test' />
<input type='input' class='test' />
<input type='input' class='test' />
<input type='input' class='test' />
<input type='input' class='test' />
<button class='save'>Save</button>
```

JQUERY

```
var saved= true;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (!saved) {
        return 'Would you like to save?';
    }
};

$('.test').on('input', function(){
    saved=false;
 });

$('.save').click(function(){
    saved=true;
});
```

If you just need to check for the input value:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    var saved= true;
    $('.test').val(function(e,v){
            //This check if the value is not empty
            //if you want any kind of value use if(v)
            if(v.trim()!=""){
                saved=false;
                return;
            }
        });
    if(!saved)
        return 'Would you like to save?';
};
```

You can achive this even with pure js:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    var saved= true,
        items= document.getElementsByClassName('test'),
        count= items.length;

    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        if(items[i].value!=""){ //if(items[i].value)
                saved=false;
                break;
            }
        };
    if(!saved)
        return 'Would you like to save?';
};
```

**EDIT COOKIE PART - FIXED - WORKS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var cookieVal = getCookie('formValue');
            if(cookieVal){
                var list=$.parseJSON(cookieVal);
                $('.test').each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('name') in list)
                        $(this).val(list[$(this).attr('name')]);
                });
                document.cookie = 'formValue=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            }
        });

        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            var saved= true;
            $('.test').each(function(){
                    if($(this).val().trim()!=""){
                        saved=false;
                        return;
                    }
                });
            if(!saved){
                var itemObj= new Object,
                    d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));

                var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
                $('.test').val(function(e,v){
                    if($(this).attr('name'))
                        itemObj[$(this).attr('name')]=v;
                });
                itemObj=JSON.stringify(itemObj);
                document.cookie = 'formValue=' + itemObj + "; " + expires;

                return 'Would you like to save?';
            }
        };

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
                    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
                        for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
                            if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
                        }
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: This second part is what I need. However, I have an issue. If I try and leave, (I.E. press the back button) all of the data is gone...there's nothing to save anymore.

Comment: Well, that's because you don't save them, the code snippet I have posted checks if there are non-empty inputs value, you must adapt it for your script. if you need also to save them with only js you can use cookies. Can you elaborate your script logic? Because this is what I get: you have a form or something ike it that once you have submitted it will be cleaned, if the user tries to leave the page with some non empty inputs then the prompt will appears, is it correct?

Comment: Yes. There is a form. If the data is accepted by the validation script it is put into a database. My client would like a functionality which I'm  trying to build. Basically, if there is new data in any of the inputs, I.E. the user has edited the value of the inputs, then if the user tries to leave the page without saving the new data (Submitting the form) then the page shoots a prompt which says "You have new data that hasn't been saved, etc." If the user says they would not like to leave the page, then they can go back to editing their data without losing their progress.

Comment: The after `saved=false` you should add your logic store the value inside a cookie and a fucntion that will be called once the page is loaded to load the values, I'm wrting something for this, I just need some time

Comment: Sorry, you should add your logic inside `if(!saved)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery already use each.

```
var leave_page_confirm = true;

$('.common_class').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0)
        leave_page_confirm = false
});
```

Also check for false if any of them are false it will always return false instead of worrying about checking every one and setting true or false. It will always be false for 1 empty.

Answer (score 0):

One crude way

```
var leave_page_confirm=false;
$('input').each(
    function(){
        if($(this).val()){
        leave_page_confirm = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var changesSaved =true;
    function hasPendingChanges()
    {
    changesSaved=$(':input.common_class').val().length == 0;
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = save_data_check;
    function save_data_check()
          {

            if (!changesSaved) {
              return "You have unsaved information on the page.";

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use change event to track any of the input has changes as,

```
var leave_page_confirm = false;
    $(function() {
        $(':input.common_class').change(function(){             
            leave_page_confirm = true;
            if(!leave_page_confirm)
            window.onbeforeunload = save_data_check;
        });
    });

    function save_data_check(){        
          return "You have unsaved information on the page.";
    }
```